# Can you change the log output format for a tornado app?

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I have a tornado server that automatically outputs logs whenever an URL is reached for example:

```
Jun 10 18:33:49 localhost server: INFO 200 GET /api/v1/profile (108.162.245.195) 0.69ms
```

I would like to change the format of these messages to include some more information like the username for example:

```
Jun 10 18:33:49 localhost server: INFO 200 GET /api/v1/profile (108.162.245.195) 0.69ms (nick@hamburger.com)
```

How can I add this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message comes from [`Application.log_request`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.log_request), so to change it you can subclass `Application` and define your own `log_request` method. (it's also possible to pass `log_function` as a keyword argument to the Application constructor if you prefer not to subclass).

The `RequestHandler` is passed to `log_request` so you can access `handler.current_user` or other methods to collect additional information to log.

Comment: Excellent, this is working fine. The only thing I'm having difficulty accessing now if the time the response took which is part of the default log output do you know if that is accessible?

Comment: Found it `handler.request.request_time()`